# Is it best to use a SIP stack or SIP client when implementing a VOIP application?

Tags: android, sip, voip

I'm working on an Android application that uses VOIP. I found a few established SIP Stacks/libraries out there (PJSIP, [JAIN SIP](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/jain-sip-tutorial-149998.pdf), MJSIP). Android seems to also have its own [Android SIP API/SDK](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip).

I was wondering if anyone had some experience using either Android's native solution or one of these libraries. If so, what are the main technical and practical differences between both?

There are also a few popular SIP Client projects out there, such as Jami, SIPDroid and [Linphone](https://www.linphone.org/) when it comes to app development on Android.

In this case, would implementing an existing SIP Client, instead of developing a new one using SIP libraries offer significant advantages?

I am mainly coding in Java and planning on using Asterisk as a SIP Server.

Comment: this question in opinion-based, thus should be closed as there is no proper answer. use solution which fits your needs best. be aware that all pointed libraries are paid (read licences) and currently newest Android 12 just deprecated built-in client (check out doc of any related class, like [`SipAudioCall`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/SipAudioCall), all marked as deprecated). It is always best to write own, reliable code, but you need A LOT of resources for that (months, maybe even year or more for single person)

Comment: Thank you Snachmsm! I'm not trying to get opinions, but understand the key factual differences between these technologies in terms of implementation.

Comment: all these are same technology/standard/protocol packed up into different library/app by different persons. thus all of these would have different APIs (a bit) and architecture. all these are existing on market so all of these have own sense of existence, some pros and cons, follow them to fit your particular case. none of them is best of worst, thats just opinion of their users

Comment: Thanks for the info again @snachmsm. I am thinking that the best option might indeed be to use an existing SIP Client solution, as I am looking to have a working prototype by the end of this summer. Although, I do wonder if it not also possible to build a simple client-server SIP feature in that time frame by using a tech stack like JAIN with Java. Also, looking at the [Telecom framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/telecom/selfManaged) it seems that Android still has some support for built-in client services?

Comment: linked doc is about usual telecommunication, this won't be gone from API for shure. only VoIP/SIP stack built-in is deprecated in Android 12, it may still be working, but you have no guarantee in which version it will stop (and this is crucial for your app). besides that I was testing this framework, has some flaws, a bit buggy and API is very limited

Comment: You've wrote that you know Java so best sample for you would be [SIPDroid](https://github.com/i-p-tel/sipdroid), as this is almost pure Java implementation of SIP. But it isn't most efficient, native libs (PJSIP, MJSIP etc.) are much faster and a bit more reliable, but for those you have to write application layer probably from scratch